# Scheduling algorithm for recurring basis

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

This was not a question about a certain piece of code but I wanna ask some recommendations and insights about this certain project of mine.

I have this project wherein the system would determine what is the best shipping date for the orders based on the date when the order was placed, in a monthly basis.  So the orders will be updated every month because a customer will register and place his order in an allowed week only in a month.  I want to deliver the parcels based on the first letters of a certain town like Aachmel, Aadmeoksh so these towns will be delivered first

I am using PHP as a backend 
my question is :

1. What algorithm should I use, should it be FIFO or any others
2. What could be the tools I use.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you going through Codecademy first (https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-angularjs). It will give you the very basics of AngularJS. After that I think you should take either CodeSchool or (even more recommended) Pluralsight. Both have free trials (2 weeks in CodeSchool and 2 months in Pluralsight) and have a course from basics (expanded in comparison to Codecademy) to expert.

So I would say: Codecademy -> Pluralsight (or if you prefer CodeSchool) -> try to do some project (you should have the knowledge of connecting backend with Angular now) -> Google the things you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you can just learn about angularJS and laravel from their documentation. Also you can refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/ for angularjs, which is helpful. and all you need to do for connecting angularjs to laravel backend is, you can create $http calls and send http request to url. The url will check laravel route and go to respective controller. Write your code in laravel controller and return the result in json format, get the response in angularjs and do stuff.

Hope this helps.